# How to get the embed url for google docs presentation?

Tags: google-docs-api

It looks like recently there has been a slight change on embedding a published google docs presentation.

The url for the iframe embed changed from:

```
https://docs.google.com/present/embed?id=[doc_id]
```

To:

```
https://docs.google.com/presentation/embed?id=[doc_id]
```

Looks like some old documents still require the old embed url, and the new documents require the new url. So given a doc_id is there a way (using the API) to get the embed url you should be using?

**update**:

After poking around, it looks like from the revision, the old doc has link tag with `rel=http://schemas.google.com/docs/2007#publish`, which contains `https://docs.google.com/present/embed?id=[doc_id]`, but on the new doc that value is `https://docs.google.com/feeds?xoauth_requestor_id=[user_email]`.

So the question is can I assume that if the link with `rel=http://schemas.google.com/docs/2007#publish` contains `https://docs.google.com/feeds?xoauth_requestor_id=[user_email]` then I need to use this url `https://docs.google.com/presentation/embed?id=[doc_id]`?

Or is it just that the API didn't include the correct value in the revision? (because I think this just happened quite recently).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The embed link has `rel="http://schemas.google.com/docs/2007#embed"` and URLs might look like `https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/PRESENTATION_ID/preview`. However, you shouldn't manually build those URLs but instead use the value of the link with `rel="http://schemas.google.com/docs/2007#embed"`.

The `xoauth_requestor_id` parameter won't be included in the embed link as that is only required when using 2-legged OAuth and impersonating a different user. If that is the authorization mechanism of your choice, you have to add those parameters yourself when adding the auth token.

Comment: Thanks Claudio! and I should add that rel="http://schemas.google.com/docs/2007#embed" should be the one from the doc entry, not the revision.