# Document embeddable url from Google Picker

Tags: google-docs-api, google-picker

I used Google Picker API to get embeddable url for spreadsheets and to show it in widget in web-app.
But currently API returns object without such URL.

> doc[google.picker.Document.EMBEDDABLE_URL] is undefined.

Is there any correct way to get embeddable url for document through API?

Comment: Based from the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/picker/docs/results), you may get `undefined` if information is not known. Refer on this [SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10889218/how-to-get-the-embed-url-for-google-docs-presentation) on how to get the embed URL but for Google docs presentation. You may also want to check on this [thread](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/NG_prWrMe4s) and see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

@GGamba

Yes, even we are facing same problem. EMBEDDABLE_URL is not being sent as part of the response. It was working until 2 days back. Though the documentation says Parameters will sent basing on the mime-type of the file. For PHOTO we have been getting this. 
Suddenly it stopped working.

I have posted a query on the Google picker forum
https://developers.google.com/picker/forum